# Facebook system user graph api for page posting

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Anyone has tried to use system user and integrate graph api's? We are facing a weird problem where the page access token (acquired from api) is throwing an error when trying to do a post:

> (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

While debugging the token all the access rights seems to be in place.

System user token -
`EAAEECKZCC5f0BANZAlGAOMlrPSkZBoZBX9oF7sMYeSkMZCDKkcdQptmJkC0IFZBugGhovODRFjCkNCjaYMyZCjHGH7VRBr2lfLkB2O5r8AXrBbm1ioh76c9rbQkZA2hFujQ6WRWjZBCXU9GQdGIomNiCLaiKEaDuDAnTQmRUYadXcuAZDZD`

Page access token -
`EAAEECKZCC5f0BAJobXRpc0EwTad4NGuLM3FsKvb7jCESbgBZAO1wWce2I8XZAqGfLu3FutbwopqknYrbrx9IFAeKTWQGZC1NWYjZBexD6A0kZCIkWLnoQBpZAsl7Cm99i2VBuJh7IPRjCZAy1vTTRkzCF2LyhtHu0Nphmt8rkWZBjebyYxJEYwcN3l6tSgQrnJAEZD`

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The absolute first thing you need to go do now, is see to it that you get both of those tokens invalidated; because otherwise anyone who finds them here can take them and make API requests using them, with all the permissions you granted. And you need to stop using fake user profiles to manage your page in the first place, otherwise you risk losing access once Facebook blocks your fake account.

Comment: Yes ofcourse we will invalidate the tokens after testing. In fact its just a test page we have created to see if we could successfully use graph api with system user access. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Tokens provided for debug purpose as they both have the expected rights even when we use graph api from postman the page access token works fine. But if we use the sdk v2.9 then it throws 200 error..

Comment: Well if it works using those tokens when you make an API request directly, but not from your code ... then maybe the problem is with the latter.

Comment: Thnx.. please find below the code for reference..

//Get Facebook Page Access Token via system user access token
$token = $this->getFacebookPageToken($auth['page_id']);
$json = json_decode($token->getBody());
                
                $page_token = $json->access_token;
                var_dump($page_token);
                $auth['access_token'] = $page_token;
// Create Facebook Connection With Our Application 
            $fb = $this->createConnectionFacebook();
            
            $linkData = [
                'message' => $caption.' '.$url,
            ];

Comment: Debug that token, and see what permissions it includes.

Comment: Thnx.. please find below the code for reference..

//Get Facebook Page Access Token via system user access token

$token = $this->getFacebookPageToken($auth['page_id']);

$json = json_decode($token->getBody());

                
                $page_token = $json->access_token;

                $auth['access_token'] = $page_token;

// Create Facebook Conne
            $fb = $this->createConnectionFacebook();

            $linkData = [
                'message' => $caption.' '.$url,
            ];

$response = $fb->post('/'.$pageId.'/feed',$linkData,$accessToken);

Comment: Yes the token has all the required permissions..

Comment: Doesn’t look like it; I don’t see for example publish_pages listed when I debug your above page access token.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?q=EAAEECKZCC5f0BAJobXRpc0EwTad4NGuLM3FsKvb7jCESbgBZAO1wWce2I8XZAqGfLu3FutbwopqknYrbrx9IFAeKTWQGZC1NWYjZBexD6A0kZCIkWLnoQBpZAsl7Cm99i2VBuJh7IPRjCZAy1vTTRkzCF2LyhtHu0Nphmt8rkWZBjebyYxJEYwcN3l6tSgQrnJAEZD&version=v2.9

Scopes rsvp_event, read_insights, publish_actions, manage_pages, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list, publish_pages, read_page_mailboxes, ads_management, ads_read, business_management

Comment: That exact same link only shows `pages_manage_cta, pages_show_list, ads_management, ads_read` for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested the correct permission ? by default, you only have public_profile. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Comment: But why do we need this considering we will be using system user token and that one has all the access rights and assets assigned..? Surprisingly we are able to request the page access token and when use the same getting this error.

Comment: is it "system user" or "admin system user". I think you need the latter one

Comment: We did try with admin system user as well but same issue.. It seems even though Facebook is returning the access token (with expected rights) but when we use that in api its returning error..